modeel = tf.keras.models.load_model('trained_model.keras')
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 modeel = tf.keras.models.load_model('trained_model.keras')

File c:\Users\arman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py:193, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    189     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(
    190         filepath, custom_objects=custom_objects, compile=compile
    191     )
    192 elif str(filepath).endswith(".keras"):
--> 193     raise ValueError(
    194         f"File not found: filepath={filepath}. "
    195         "Please ensure the file is an accessible `.keras` "
    196         "zip file."
    197     )
    198 else:
    199     raise ValueError(
    200         f"File format not supported: filepath={filepath}. "
    201         "Keras 3 only supports V3 `.keras` files and "
   (...)
    210         "might have a different name)."
    211     )

ValueError: File not found: filepath=trained_model.keras. Please ensure the file is an accessible `.keras` zip file.

file is in same directory also.
How do I solve this error?

have you tried using these following command to see if you are indeed in the path-> list all files  your directory: import os print(os.listdir()) and  working directory: print(os.getcwd())

Is your model saved in the same folder you are working in? If not, then perhaps copy the model into the folder you are currently working or specify the entire path to the saved model.
